# Base64 to nparray and viceversa as fast as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, base64

Currently my Python server receives a base64 encoded PNG image  and converts it to nparray as follows:

```
input = data['frame'].split(",")[1]
img_data = base64.b64decode(input)
nparr = np.frombuffer(img_data, np.uint8)
img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

And viceversa:

```
retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', output)
pic_str = base64.b64encode(buffer)
pic_str = pic_str.decode()
image_data = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + pic_str
```

However it takes too much time for my real time application, does a faster way to do this exist? Between the two operations the nparray is converted to a Tensor (and viceversa) so a base64 <-> Tensor conversion would be fine too.

Comment: how about not encoding to base64, but sending binary data?

Comment: I have already tried but sending (and receiving) the raw data from the client and skipping the decoding/encoding part from the answer below forces me to convert the image explicitly to an RGB image before using it for my operations and the time it takes slows down the whole procedure.

Comment: you are mixing things up. I mean *do not* do the base64 encode/decode, but do perform channel order transformations, if you need them.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself correctly. If I send the binary data to the server and opening it as an Image I do not get an RGB image (using BytesIo and Image), the operations to convert it to what I want take too much time.

Comment: then you should investigate why that happens. in any case, base64 conversions are an *additional* step, not a necessary step, and so you should avoid that. imencode/imdecode convert between plain bitmap data and compressed data (e.g. JPEG). those functions do not AT ALL require any b64 encoding. see if you can avoid the "data:image/jpeg;base64," stuff and send binary data, i.e. the data you have BEFORE you do a `b64encode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed update will depend on the size of the input image. But the following method works a bit faster for me:

- Encoding

  ```
  def arr_to_base64(image: np.ndarray, ext='jpeg'):
      """ Convert an array to an image source that can be displayed."""
      image = Image.fromarray(image)
      if ext == 'jpg': ext = 'jpeg'
      if ext == 'jpeg' and image.mode in ('RGBA', 'A'):
          background = Image.new(image.mode[:-1], image.size, (255, 255, 255))
          background.paste(image, image.split()[-1])
          image = background

      buffer = io.BytesIO()
      image.save(buffer, format=ext)
      encoded = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
      return f'data:image/{ext};base64,' + encoded
  ```
- Decoding

  ```
  def arr_from_base64(base_string):
      msg = base64.b64decode(base_string[23:])  # Chop of metadata from above
      buf = io.BytesIO(msg)
      img = Image.open(buf)
      return np.array(img)
  ```

The following tests have been performed by running the operation 100 times, for a random input image (`np.random.randint(0, 255, (n, n, 3), dtype=np.uint8)`).

For 100 times encoding a `(n, n, 3)` image:

[image]

For 100 times encoding and decoding a `(n, n, 3)` image:

[image]

### Notes

- Please don't use built-in as variables (`input`).
- The time spend on this seems to  be very non-significant. For large images of, 512 by 512, you are still able to run around 80 images per second. You need around 23, to get a good real life feed. Maybe you want to check the real time drain.

Comment: This actually gave me a slight improvement, and thank you for the other tips.